# Concatenate/paste together multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a dataframe with multiple observations (the amount and their names vary often) with minimum and maximum values. Example:

```
ID O1_min O1_max O2_min O2_max O3_min O3_max
A  1      2      1      2      1      2
B  1      2      1      2      1      2
C  1      2      1      2      1      2
D  1      2      1      2      1      2
```

I want to go through my data frame and transform all _min and _max columns in a _range column for each observation. So it would look like this:

```
ID O1_range O2_range O3_range
A  1:2      1:2      1:2
B  1:2      1:2      1:2
C  1:2      1:2      1:2
D  1:2      1:2      1:2
```

I was using `paste()` function but that won't solve my problem, once new columns can enter the dataframe at any time and I'd like to have a more automatic code.

Comment: Are the `_range` column elements real vectors, or are they strings that look like `"1:2"`?

Comment: They can be strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose columns have the same naming convention, you can use `purrr::map2_dfc()`.

### Prepare data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)


data <- read_delim("ID O1_min O1_max O2_min O2_max O3_min O3_max
A  1      2      1      2      1      2
B  1      2      1      2      1      2
C  1      2      1      2      1      2
D  1      2      1      2      1      2",delim = " ") %>%
    mutate_all(str_trim)
```

### To answer your question

```r
# concatenation
result <- map2_dfc(select(data,ends_with("min")),
                   select(data,ends_with("max")),
                   function(x,y){
    str_c(x,":",y)
})


# rename columns
colnames(result) <- str_replace(colnames(result),pattern = "_.+","range")

#result
bind_cols(data[,1],result)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  ID    O1range O2range O3range
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 A     1:2     1:2     1:2    
2 B     1:2     1:2     1:2    
3 C     1:2     1:2     1:2    
4 D     1:2     1:2     1:2
```

Comment: You can simplify your code by replacing `data[,min_cols_position]` and `data[,max_cols_position]` with `select(df, ends_with("_min"))` and `select(df, ends_with("_max"))` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, this is much easier. I modified my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
df <- data.frame(df[1], 
                 mapply(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ":"), 
                        df[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)],  df[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)]))

colnames(df) <- sub("\\_.*", "\\1", colnames(df))

  ID  O1  O2  O3
1  A 1:2 1:2 1:2
2  B 1:2 1:2 1:2
3  C 1:2 1:2 1:2
4  D 1:2 1:2 1:2
```

If you need to name your columns with `_range`, then you can replace the last line with:

```
colnames(df)[2:length(df)] <- paste0("O", 1:(length(df) - 1), "_range")

  ID O1_range O2_range O3_range
1  A      1:2      1:2      1:2
2  B      1:2      1:2      1:2
3  C      1:2      1:2      1:2
4  D      1:2      1:2      1:2
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID O1_min O1_max O2_min O2_max O3_min O3_max
A  1      2      1      2      1      2
                 B  1      2      1      2      1      2
                 C  1      2      1      2      1      2
                 D  1      2      1      2      1      2",
                 header = TRUE,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit lengthy but does the trick, plus can handle more columns if they follow the same naming format.

```r
df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:4],A1_min=c(1:4),A1_max=c(2:5),
                 B1_min=c(3:6),B1_max=c(4:7))

df %>% gather(k,v,-id) %>% 
  mutate(cat=str_split_fixed(k,'_',2)[,1],
         val=str_split_fixed(k,'_',2)[,2]) %>% 
  select(-k) %>% spread(val,v) %>% 
  mutate(range=paste0(min,'-',max)) %>% 
  select(-max,-min) %>% spread(cat,range)

  id  A1  B1
1  a 1-2 3-4
2  b 2-3 4-5
3  c 3-4 5-6
4  d 4-5 6-7
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with `gather` and `spread` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(var, value, -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, col = sub('_[a-z]+$', '', var)) %>%
  summarize(value = paste(value, collapse = ":")) %>%
  spread(col, value) %>%
  rename_at(vars(-ID), paste0, "_range")
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID    O1_range O2_range O3_range
  <fct> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 A     1:2      1:2      1:2     
2 B     1:2      1:2      1:2     
3 C     1:2      1:2      1:2     
4 D     1:2      1:2      1:2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), O1_min = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), O1_max = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), O2_min = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), O2_max = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), O3_min = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), O3_max = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have more than 1 ID?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in base R using `Map`. I used @avid_useR's data. This uses `Map` to paste alternating columns (minus the ID column) and assigns them to your new columns names `[paste0("O", 1:3, "_range")]`. Hope this helps!

```
df_new <- data.frame(ID = df1$ID, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_new[paste0("O", 1:3, "_range")] <- Map(paste, df1[-1][c(T,F)], df1[-1][c(F,T)], sep = ":")

df_new
  df1.ID O1_range O2_range O3_range
1      A      1:2      1:2      1:2
2      B      1:2      1:2      1:2
3      C      1:2      1:2      1:2
4      D      1:2      1:2      1:2
```